# How does this repeat() function work? Help me understand

Tags: javascript, css, methods

I'm learning Javascript and found this solution on how to make a 16X16 grid. so far i've used  **example.repeat(number)** with a an integer value. I somewhat get the flow of the code but I cant grasp how repeat works here exactly, kindly help.

Result on codepen: https://codepen.io/shogunhermit15/pen/mdxyqMN?editors=1010

```js
function buildGrid(x, y, cellSize, gridElement) {
  gridElement.style.display = "grid";
  gridElement.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${x}, ${cellSize}px)`;
  gridElement.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${y}, ${cellSize}px)`;
 
  let squares = new DocumentFragment();

  for (let i = 0; i < x * y; i++) {
    let square = document.createElement('div');
    square.className = 'square';
    squares.appendChild(square);
  }

  gridElement.appendChild(squares);
}


buildGrid(16, 16, 25,  document.querySelector(".grid"));
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work because you didn't include your html. What part of the function aren't you grasping?

Comment: What do you mean when you say `example.repeat()' you code is not using a repeat function

Comment: That's a CSS thing, not JavaScript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat

Comment: Thank you @slebetman. I initially thought the repeat was js method repeat(). This clears up everything

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is not related to javascript.
It is related to the CSS repeat function.

The repeat() CSS function represents a repeated fragment of the track list, allowing a large number of columns or rows that exhibit a recurring pattern to be written in a more compact form.

Here is Mdn refrence where You can learn more:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat

Comment: It didn't cross my mind at the time that it might have been a css funtion, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You will find here your code with each line commented, hoping that it helps you to understand your code correctly.

```
function buildGrid(x, y, cellSize, gridElement) { // declaration of the buildGrid function which takes as parameters the location of the grid, the size of the cell, and the element of the grid
    gridElement.style.display = "grid"; // grid display is set to grid
    gridElement.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${x}, ${cellSize}px)`; // set grid size based on cell size
    gridElement.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${y}, ${cellSize}px)`; // set grid size based on cell size
   
    let squares = new DocumentFragment(); // creating the squares object which contains the grid elements
  
    for (let i = 0; i < x * y; i++) { // loop that creates grid cells
      let square = document.createElement('div'); // creating a div element
      square.className = 'square'; // adding square class to cell
      squares.appendChild(square); // adding the cell to the grid
    }
  
    gridElement.appendChild(squares); // adding grid to page element
  }
  
  
  buildGrid(16, 16, 25,  document.querySelector(".grid")); // call buildGrid function with defined parameters
```

Comment: You managed to avoid explaining `repeat`. Did you read the question?

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me. could you expound more on the repeat bit. I've tried searching on how that method could be used in the same format as the example but nothing came up. I figured maybe the repeat would be treated as a string inside the template literals but the code seems to be running fine

Comment: Nevermind actually, a comment made me realize that it's a css function, not js.